# Hashed RowKeys Vs Monotonically Increasing RowKeys

Tags: hbase

I've read in multiple places that hashing monotonically increasing rowkeys helps prevent region hotspotting by distributing the data

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17969852/4495849

http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#rowkey.design

My concern is that this will add too many seeks, defeating the the benefit of hdfs.  Is there ever a scenario where keeping the rowkeys unhashed would yield better performance.  Does the benefit of better distribution outweigh the increased seek time?

My rowkey is a combination of timestamp and id.  There are about 20,000 ids and 525600 (a year of minute readings) per id.  Requests are made for small and large groups of ids over many small or large time ranges

Answer (score 2):

Some times, unhashed keys give benifits.
When you need to read a some significant portion of data that in some range e.g. all strings in from 'xxx' to 'zzz'. Unhashed keys will give you a considerable benefits in this case. You can use scan with start and sot rows keys. HBase will read only this data. In case of hashed keys you will need to scan hole table and to filter values according this range criterion.